# What does it mean to handle state change of entity only when Unchanged to the Modified?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[Article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/basics/entity-states.aspx) says:

> The Context not only holds the reference to all the entity objects as
>   soon as retrieved from the database, but also keeps track of entity
>   states and maintains modifications made to the properties of the
>   entity. This feature is known as Change Tracking.
>
> The change in entity state from the Unchanged to the Modified state is
>   the only state that's automatically handled by the context. All other
>   changes must be made explicitly using proper methods of DbContext or
>   DbSet.

What should i do in case of other state changes (e.g. Unchanged to Deleted)?

Comment: You have to use `Context.Entity.Remove(entity)` for state change to `Deleted`. Or you can explicitly change state with `Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted`.

Comment: What does it mean that the context "handles" state change from Unchanged to Modified?

Comment: When you get any entity like `var entity = Context.Entry.Find(id);` at that time `entity` object has state `Unchanged`. But then if you change any of the property value from `entity` object then `Change Tracker` will automatically change its state to 'Modified'.

Comment: Do i have to handle (change) an entity's state (transition) manually whenever i modify or add/delete entitys?

Comment: No, `Context.Add` `Context.Remove` etc methods will automatically change `state`. You don't need to do that manually. This link might be helpful for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking